# How to fix error "System.Exception: Exception from HRESULT: 0xE0000204" when using SerialDevice.GetDeviceSelector("COM1")?

Tags: c#, uwp, modbus

I'm using SerialDevice Class and got an exception in the following code:

```
string selector = SerialDevice.GetDeviceSelector("COM1");
```

The exception is as followed:
    System.Exception: Exception from HRESULT: 0xE0000204 
    at Windows.Devices.SerialCommunication.SerialDevice.GetDeviceSelector(String portName)

How can I fix this exception?

Comment: I can not reproduce this error. Could you please tell me if you tested this issue on another development machine?

Comment: No, I didn't try on other machines.

Comment: Are you sure that you have a COM1 port?  

Many computers don't have built in serial ports anymore.  However, I think the Windows OS often still marks them as reserved so when you add something like a USB - serial port, it actually shows up as COM3 (or higher).   

If you are developing a Windows UWP application (maybe even WPF), I don't think those frameworks are allowed (permissions) to open COM1/COM2.